# In Bash concatenated within an if comparison

Tags: bash

I want to check if a file exists by using a if comparison for a base path concatenated with a file name. I'm trying things like:

```
declare -r BasePath="/some/path"

if [ -f "$BasePath" "/my_file.txt" ]
then
    #do something
fi
```

I just can't get the concatenation of the variable holding the base path with the string literal to work within the comparison.

Comment: At the very least, remove the space between the two strings. Quotes do not define complete values in shell; they simply escape the characters between them. `"$BasePath""/my_file.txt"` is valid, and completely equivalent to `"$BasePath/my_file.txt"` or `"$BasePath"/my_file.txt` (either of which would be a common way to write this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
if [ -f "$BasePath/my_file.txt" ]
```